# How to identify function outputs so I can make "pretty output" and/or reduce amount of output

Tags: r

How can I determine what are the stored variables in a function such as `t.test`?

For example, I may want to only output one of the following at a time:
t,df,p-value, confidence interval or mean.

An example would be: mean=6.9 or c.i.=(2.9,4.5)

```
t.test(x,y,paired=TRUE,alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided")

        Paired t-test

data:  x and y
t = -3.5292, df = 31, p-value = 0.001325
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 5
95 percent confidence interval:
 2.006935 4.199315
sample estimates:
mean of the differences 
               3.103125
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first part of the question about identifying outputs from a model, use `str` always to find the structure

```
# using `mtcars` data as reproducible 
out <- with(mtcars, t.test(mpg, hp, paired = TRUE, 
          alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided"))
```

The model outputs are usually in a `list` and by checking the `str` confirms it

```
> str(out)
List of 10
 $ statistic  : Named num -10.2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "t"
 $ parameter  : Named num 31
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "df"
 $ p.value    : num 2.24e-11
 $ conf.int   : num [1:2] -153 -100
  ..- attr(*, "conf.level")= num 0.95
 $ estimate   : Named num -127
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "mean of the differences"
 $ null.value : Named num 5
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "difference in means"
 $ stderr     : num 13
 $ alternative: chr "two.sided"
 $ method     : chr "Paired t-test"
 $ data.name  : chr "mpg and hp"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "htest"
```

Now, we can extract the components from the `list` with standard extractors (`$` or `[[`)

```
> out$statistic
     t 
-10.15041 
> out$conf.int
[1] -153.0385 -100.1552
attr(,"conf.level")
[1] 0.95
> out$p.value
[1] 2.240928e-11
```

This can be done in a more easier by wrapping with `tidy` from `broom`

```
library(broom)
tidy(t.test(x,y,paired=TRUE,alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided"))
```

Reproducible example with `mtcars`

```
tidy(with(mtcars, t.test(mpg, hp, paired = TRUE, alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided")))
# A tibble: 1 × 8
  estimate statistic  p.value parameter conf.low conf.high method        alternative
     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <chr>         <chr>      
1    -127.     -10.2 2.24e-11        31    -153.     -100. Paired t-test two.sided
```

---

The output from `tidy` is a `tibble`, so we can `select` the columns of interest

```
library(dplyr)
tidy(with(mtcars, t.test(mpg, hp, paired = TRUE, alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided"))) %>%
    select(estimate, conf.low, conf.high)
```

Comment: that was not the question `How can I determine what are the stored variables in a function such as t.test?`

Comment: That is helpful. Is there a way I can extract only one at a time say estimate or conf.low?

Comment: I like raw r...

Comment: @rawr in the second line it says `I may want to only output one of the following `

Comment: @MaryA.Marion please check the updated solution

Comment: so now we're up to two packages that still does not answer the question and would not work for any object not covered by `broom::tidy`

Comment: @rawr The OP mentioned clearly ` t,df,p-value, confidence interval or mean` which are all returned in tidy

Comment: I am saving this conversation and will definitely think twice about how I ask my questions! Touche!

Comment: @MaryA.Marion sorry, I don't understand the isue with solution.  Your question title was `How to identify function outputs so I can make "pretty output" and/or reduce amount of output`. The `tidy` output is pretty output and it reduces/. So, I don't really understand the issue here

Comment: I program in R to write sentences which I can easily add to a report.

Comment: Isn't the tidy output easily output as a table or write as a table

Comment: Yes it makes a good table. I may want to reduce the number of items in that table however.

Comment: @MaryA.Marion I updated with `select` step which I am not sure whether you see it or not `tidy(with(mtcars, t.test(mpg, hp, paired = TRUE, alpha=.10,mu=5,alternative="two.sided"))) %>%
    select(estimate, conf.low, conf.high)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237934/discussion-between-mary-a-marion-and-akrun).